# How to change the cursor color on emacs

Tags: colors, emacs, text-cursor

I made some changes in Emacs's colors and the only thing wrong now is the cursor that is black on black background and I will have to change that.  What do I do?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are running a recent version of emacs you can use:

```
; Set cursor color to white
(set-cursor-color "#ffffff")
```

Instead of `#ffffff` you can use any color you like. For a list of hex code google Says: http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

---

Maybe you like this one... the following code changes the cursor color on each *blink*. Just eval code and its running:

```
; Using in Emacs 24.0 

(defvar blink-cursor-colors (list  "#92c48f" "#6785c5" "#be369c" "#d9ca65")
  "On each blink the cursor will cycle to the next color in this list.")

(setq blink-cursor-count 0)
(defun blink-cursor-timer-function ()
  "Zarza wrote this cyberpunk variant of timer `blink-cursor-timer'. 
Warning: overwrites original version in `frame.el'.

This one changes the cursor color on each blink. Define colors in `blink-cursor-colors'."
  (when (not (internal-show-cursor-p))
    (when (>= blink-cursor-count (length blink-cursor-colors))
      (setq blink-cursor-count 0))
    (set-cursor-color (nth blink-cursor-count blink-cursor-colors))
    (setq blink-cursor-count (+ 1 blink-cursor-count))
    )
  (internal-show-cursor nil (not (internal-show-cursor-p)))
  )
```

Note that this code replaces the emacs function 'blink-cursor-timer-function' from 'frame.el'.

Comment: Note that the first suggestion here will only affect the current frame. If you want to change the color for all new frames, modify `default-frame-alist` as suggested by @TreyJackson in his answer.

Answer (score 21):

None of above worked for me, so I did a little research on my own. From [the Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html):

> 14.20 Displaying the Cursor
>
> On a text terminal, **the cursor's appearance is controlled by the
> terminal**, largely out of the control of Emacs. Some terminals offer
> two different cursors: a “visible” static cursor, and a “very visible”
> blinking cursor. By default, Emacs uses the very visible cursor, and
> switches to it when you start or resume Emacs. If the variable
> visible-cursor is nil when Emacs starts or resumes, it uses the normal
> cursor.
>
> On a graphical display, many more properties of the text cursor can be
> altered. To customize its color, change the :background attribute of
> the face named cursor (see Face Customization). (The other attributes
> of this face have no effect; the text shown under the cursor is drawn
> using the frame's background color.) To change its shape, customize
> the buffer-local variable cursor-type; possible values are box (the
> default), hollow (a hollow box), bar (a vertical bar), (bar . n) (a
> vertical bar n pixels wide), hbar (a horizontal bar), (hbar . n) (a
> horizontal bar n pixels tall), or nil (no cursor at all).
>
> To disable cursor blinking, change the variable blink-cursor-mode to
> nil (see Easy Customization), or add the line (blink-cursor-mode 0) to
> your init file. Alternatively, you can change how the cursor looks
> when it “blinks off” by customizing the list variable
> blink-cursor-alist. Each element in the list should have the form
> (on-type . off-type); this means that if the cursor is displayed as
> on-type when it blinks on (where on-type is one of the cursor types
> described above), then it is displayed as off-type when it blinks off.
>
> Some characters, such as tab characters, are “extra wide”. When the
> cursor is positioned over such a character, it is normally drawn with
> the default character width. You can make the cursor stretch to cover
> wide characters, by changing the variable x-stretch-cursor to a
> non-nil value.
>
> The cursor normally appears in non-selected windows as a non-blinking
> hollow box. (For a bar cursor, it instead appears as a thinner bar.)
> To turn off cursors in non-selected windows, change the variable
> cursor-in-non-selected-windows to nil.
>
> To make the cursor even more visible, you can use HL Line mode, a
> minor mode that highlights the line containing point. Use M-x
> hl-line-mode to enable or disable it in the current buffer. M-x
> global-hl-line-mode enables or disables the same mode globally.

So here is the way to do it:

1. `M-x customize-face`, enter
2. `cursor` enter
3. choose the background color of you liking.
4. click on state, save for future sessions.

Screenshots here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat.   It also looks like you can click on the `Apply and Save` button shown at the top of your screenshot.  A bright red cursor for me.  My matching paren indicator colors are too dark, and the color hides the (rainbow) parens, so all I see is two solid colored blocks.  To change the matching parens color to something lighter (white for me), see here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/76410

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
  '((cursor-color . "palegoldenrod")))
```

If you want to preserve the other values in `default-frame-alist` you can us Mark's suggestion:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(cursor-color . "palegoldenrod"))
```

Comment: `default-frame-alist` usually contains some X specific staff (such as default frame size) already. Did you mean `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(cursor-color . "palegoldenrod"))`?

Comment: @Henry That's reasonable, though `default-frame-alist` on my build of Emacs seems to default to just `((menu-bar-lines . 1) (tool-bar-lines . 1))` - which wouldn't be sorely missed.  Adjusting answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you use X window system, try out put something like this to `.Xdefaults`:

```
*cursorColor: #ff7700
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, setting the cursor color on init with the recommendation from the other answers wouldn't really work because of some possible interference with the themes and packages I was loading. My solution was to add the following instead:

```el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
          (lambda () (run-with-timer 5 nil #'set-cursor-color "SystemRedColor")))
```

This solution makes it so that a call to set-cursor-color will only happen 5 seconds after init finishes, allowing enough time for all the other packages and theme changes to fully load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for customize emacs colors:

```
(defun good-colors ()
  (progn
     ;; Set cursor color
     (set-cursor-color "Black")

     (set-background-color "grey46")
     (set-foreground-color "White")
     (set-border-color "dark orange")
     (set-mouse-color "dark orange") 
))

(good-colors)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `progn` wrapper in this instance (i.e. at the top level of a function).

Comment: This did not make any change on the color of the cursor @0xAX

Comment: this sets all buffer's background

Answer (score 1):

There is also a command line option:

```
--cursor-color, -cr COLOR       color of the Emacs cursor indicating point
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind if you are using `iTerm2` you have to make changes on its settings, otherwise changes on the `.emacs` config file does not take place.

`Preferences => Profiles => Color => Cursor Colors`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added `(set-face-attribute 'cursor nil :background "#A0F")` to my `.emacs`  file, making my cursor a nice violet color.

I'm not sure how critical version and system info are, but I'm running GNU Emacs 27.1 in GUI mode on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. (Emacs 28.2 is available from the GNU website, so YMMV.)